# Upload file to twitter using GUI Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, automation, ui-automation

I try to upload an image to twitter using the GUI with python and selenium. However, selenium cannot access the machine's dialog for choosing a file in my system. How do I send keys for the path of my image plus enter in the file choosing dialog?

Edit: I solved this question by doing so:

```
import pyautogui

#clicking on button
pyautogui.write(imagePath)
pyautogui.press('enter')
```

when the file selection dialog appeared.